# How do I add an application to a specific sub-category of dash

Tags: unity

I tried to use "main menu" for this but while it was added to "main menu" it doesn't display in dash in the similarly named sub category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my best knowledge this is solely decided by the *Category*-key of the application's *.desktop* file (either located in `/usr/share/applications/` or for local user applications in `~/.local/share/applications/`).

E.g.:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop | grep Categories
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;

$ cat /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop | grep Categories
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
```